# Scraping a link further

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to currently scrape https://rl.insider.gg/en/xbox and trying to identify the "trending" items on the page

I have somehow got up to the point where I had the links, but could not figure out how to parse them further.  I wanted and wanted to extract the last part from them and store the two values in two variables: colour and item

Eg:(an example of a link I have right now)

`/en/xbox/octane/white`

I would like to take off the en and xbox bit to only leave the `octane/white`.  Then, store the `octane` as a variable called item and the `white` as a variable called colour

What I have so far

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get("https://rl.insider.gg/en/xbox")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

trendingitems = soup.find(id="trendingItems")
for link in trendingitems.find_all('a'):
  linkitems = (link.get('href'))
  print(linkitems)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get("https://rl.insider.gg/en/xbox")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

trending_items = soup.find(id="trendingItems")
for link in trending_items.find_all('a'):
    link_items = link.get('href').replace('/en/xbox/', '')
    split_items = link_items.split('/')
    if len(split_items) == 2:
        item = split_items[0]
        colour = split_items[1]
```

I count the split_items since some return values don't have a color. If I get a result of 2, we know we already have the item and colour.

```
octane/white
zomba/white
fennec
fennec/white
dissolver
mainframe
interstellar
octane/crimson
dueling_dragons
standard/black
emerald/white
mainframe/white
octane/sblue
big_splash
octane/lime
stipple_gait
emerald/black
helios/white
interstellar/white
standard/white
20xx
dieci_uncommon/black
fire_god
heatwave
zomba
```

Comment: tysm works almost perfect - would there be any way to also show the item when it has no paint? - just because when running it seems to ignore the items with no paint

Comment: add elif statement and add empty value to colour
elif len(split_items) == 1:
     item = split_items[0]
     colour = ''

Comment: oh nvm i think i worked it out by using an if len(spli_items) == 1:
item = split_items[0]